# Requesting data from an API using Net::HTTP before a user logs in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recurring-billing, net-http

I'm trying to integrate my Ruby on Rails application with CheddarGetter using their hosted payment pages (http://support.cheddargetter.com/kb/hosted-payment-pages/hosted-payment-pages-setup-guide).

I pretty much have everything figured out except for the last part -- checking customer data against their API to make sure that the customer is still active before letting him log-in your system.

Apparently it involves some sort of HTTP request, which to be honest I am not at all familiar with, sorry. Here's the code:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://yoursite.chargevault.com/status?key=a1b2c3d4e6&code=yourcustomercode")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
status = http.request(request).body
```

I'm wondering where exactly do I put this code?

I'm thinking put the following in my `user_session.rb` model:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  before_create :check_status

  private
  def check status
      # insert above code here
  end
end
```

But I'm not too sure..? I suspect there also has to be some `if active? elsif cancelled? && pending?` code in there, referring to the response that the CheddarGetter API will give you..

Would appreciate some direction, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting that in it's own module in the `/lib` directory and also wrapping the call in a `Timeout` in case the website you are trying to access is unavailable.  I just made a generic example below, so you can tweak the time as needed.

**Inside /lib/customer_status.rb**

```
require 'timeout'
module CustomerStatus
  class << self
    def get_status
      begin
        Timeout::timeout(30) {
          uri = URI.parse("https://yoursite.chargevault.com/status?key=a1b2c3d4e6&code=yourcustomercode")
          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
          status = http.request(request).body
        } # end timeout

        return status

      rescue Exception => e
        # This will catch a timeout error or any other network connectivity error
        Rails.logger.error "We had an error getting the customer's status: #{e}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  # include the new module we added
  include CustomerStatus

  before_create :check_status

  private
  def check status
    raise someError unless (CustomerStatus.get_status.include?("active"))
  end
end
```

I'll let you add in the other logic for `cancelled`, `pending` etc states as well as passing in the customer info to the new module method.  You may just want to use a switch statement for handling different states.

---

**Update**

Also, if you don't already have this in your `config/application.rb` file, make sure you include it so it adds the `lib` folder to the autoload path:

```
module YourAppNameGoesHere
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to write a very detailed reply. I tried the code on my app just to see if it would work, and I got an "uninitialized constant UserSession::CustomerStatus" error. What do you think is going wrong?

Comment: Did you restart your Rails server?

Comment: Also, check my updated answer so you make sure to add the `lib` folder to the Rails autoload path so it knows to load that module on start.

Comment: I did, yes. It seems like it has no idea what to do with CustomerStatus in the user_session.rb model if I'm reading it right. Either that, or my current_user methods are getting in the way somehow..

Comment: Can you please verify that the `lib` folder was added to the autoloads path?

Comment: Yep, it is. Uncommented the autoload_paths and added /lib to the end. Restarted server, still the same error.

Comment: Oh wait... No longer getting an error! Progress!!! :D Now I'm only getting "undefined method `redirect_to'" so I think the customer_status.rb is working perfectly now.

Comment: lol Yeah I had a brain fart and accidentally put `redirect_to` in there.  You should really be raising an error or adding some validation error in that method.  See update.  Hope this helps!

Comment: One of these days we will meet in real life and I will buy you beers for a whole week :) thanks a whole lot!!!